# Use headers not available at compile time

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, header-files

I am using Qt 5 and I have a plugin system using shared libraries. i.e I have a main window that loads 'plugins' at runtime, which are in the form of shared libraries.

I use an interface that stands between the main window and the factory for the plugin, but currently both the main window and the library need to have this header at compile time.

How can I avoid this duplicity? Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there's any duplication here; you have an interface definition, and both sides of the interface need to be able to "see" that definition.

Comment: Okay, I didn't like how both sources had to have a copy of the header, and I wasn't sure if there was a better way, thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need a *copy*.  Just expose an `include` directory from your main plugin system, and make sure that's added to the include path of the compiler when compiling the individual plugins.

Comment: Normally when you want to use a a software package, you install it on your machine. This involves copying of binaries and headers to some place where other programs can see them, both at run time and at compile time. Of course this is not *strictly* required and you may tell other programs to search the build directory of your plugin system. But for any large project this goes out of hand quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used cmake's include_directories() function to expose the headers src dir to the plugin at compile time. If the main exe is already installed, it can grab the headers from the install directory.
Thanks to Oli Charlesworth and n.m.